# convert programmer's function into math notation

Tags: equation, mathjax, converters, notation, asciimath

Could you please advise any online tools which automatically converts programmers' code function of type:

```
s = k * ((a* x ^ n) / (1 + (a* x ^ n)))
```

into math notation like this:

```
$$s(x) = k {{a x ^ n} \over 1 + a x ^ n}$$
```

which is supposed to display this:

[image]

(It works on Cross Validated but seems not to work here).

I am using [mathjax](https://www.mathjax.org/#demo) but I have to manually write the code from scratch which is a laborious task with complex functions, not to mention that handcraft is good for art, not for math notation.

For example I would like to convert this function:

```
A = (F1 / ((1 - F1)) / (G1 ^ (Log((F1 * (1 - F2) / (F2 * (1 - F1)))) / (Log(G1 / G2)))))
```

It's easy to get lost in levels of `/` character.

I have found [asciimath](http://asciimath.org/) It produces correct results but I do not know if it is possible to grab the result displayed in the window on the right hand side as this mathjax code.

Comment: Just google ["asciimath to latex"](https://www.intmath.com/help/asciimath-input-latex-katex-output.php)

Comment: I don't meant one sentence being an qualitative answer, but as you wish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just google ["asciimath to latex"](https://www.intmath.com/help/asciimath-input-latex-katex-output.php)

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean this site: https://www.intmath.com/help/asciimath-input-latex-katex-output.php Do you recommend "asciimath to latex" as general phrase to search the web for direction to find different tools? In either way it would be beneficial for SO to write a few words to uncover what is under the link. BTW I am just guessing the verb  "to search" or "to look for" might be good enough for instructions to find it:-)